# Ruby Sockets via proxy

Tags: ruby, sockets, modbus

Is is possible to use Socks5 proxy when communicating over Ruby Socket?

I need to communicate with a Modbus device from a fixed IP. As my Rails app is hosted on Heroku, I'm thinking about using IPBurger addon to get the fixed IP. The addon gives me a Socks5/HTTP and HTTPS proxies. The Modbus library I want to use (RModbus) is build using Sockets:
https://github.com/rmodbus/rmodbus/blob/master/lib/rmodbus/tcp.rb

I'm considering forking the library and making the necessary changes to be able to pass the proxy details to it. How can I define a proxy in the Ruby Socket? What are my other options?

Comment: Your Heroku app needs to pipe through Socks? Please include a communication flowchart in the question which shows where the Socks proxy is located, otherwise it's quite difficult to figure out what you are trying to do.

Comment: In simple terms I want to use Rmodbus with a fixed IP on Heroku